# Closing Bootstrap modals in android with phonegap

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, modal-dialog

I am using [this bootstrap modals (popups)](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-modals/) and they work great in my browser. The problem is, when I launch them on android using phonegap, they do not close when the close button is pressed. When I click on the ovelay next to the popup, everything seems to be working alright ;/ I am very confised...

EDIT: I use exactly the same code as in the example and something goes wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this function to my angular.js controller:

```
$scope.closeModal = function (idOfModal) {
    $(idOfModal).modal('hide');
}
```

And also to the confirm/save buttons of modals, after the controller's function is executed, at the very end again I add `$(idOfModal).modal('hide');`, where I also pass `idOfModal` to the function ;)

Comment: $scope.closeModal <- is this Angular only? What should i be doing instead? I'm not using Angular. Tried to hide it when on a onclick method. Even tried te remove the modal ! the modal itself will disappear but the div with the opacity will still be there !

Comment: $scope.closeModal is a function. You should inject "$scope" in your angularJS controller, then using my snippet you can add ng-click="closeModal" to the close button of the modal or just call the function. "$(idOfModal).modal('hide');" is what closes the modal, the others are just to connect it to the ng-view. You should also include jquery ;)

Comment: @DennisAnderson Angular makes $scope available: that part is angular, raw bootstrap would be something like `$('#my-modal').modal('hide')`